# Get soapenv:Header section in server side

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

For authentication, I need to get parameters of soap header when clients call me.
I googled couple of hours but nothing found.

```
class myClass {

function syncRelation($params) {
    Functions::logging($params);
}

$server = new SoapClient('sag_data.wsdl');
$server->setClass('myClass');
$server->handle();
```

At above code, I want to authenticate request before `syncRelation` function.

Comment: Hello Mohsen. Did you use the search function of stackoverflow? Perhaps this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657954/some-errors-implementing-soap-web-service-with-php/51660083#51660083